# Prevent Apache httpcore from slow denial of service attack

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, ddos, apache-httpasyncclient

I am using apache httpcore library to listen for http requests as below.

```
IOReactorConfig config = IOReactorConfig.custom() // Create instance of a custom Builder
                    .setTcpNoDelay(true) //
                    // Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. InputStream associated
                    // with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
                    // java.net.SocketTimeoutException
                    // is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the
                    // blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted
                    // as an infinite timeout.
                    .setSoTimeout(PropertiesStorage.getCcsSocketTimeoutMilis()) //
                    .setSoReuseAddress(true) //
                    .setConnectTimeout(PropertiesStorage.getCcsConnectionTimeoutMilis()) //
                    // Determines the number of I/O dispatch threads to be used by the I/O reactor.
                    .setIoThreadCount(PropertiesStorage.getCcsDispatchThreadCount()) //
                    .build();

// Create instance of a server - reactor
private static ListeningIOReactor ioReactor = new  DefaultListeningIOReactor(config);

// Listening on specific port
ioReactor.listen(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT));
```

I want to configure mod_reqtimeout, mod_qos and mod_security, to prevent from "slow denial of service". But I am not sure how do I configure these params. 
Can you please help ?